# Several vim/emmet commands command not working

Tags: vim, emmet

I have tried emmet trigger key for various cases in vim.
Each is supposed to do a specific task.
But little if anything happens.
The one trigger key that works as described in the docs is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>.

Several vim/emmet commands below not working.

```
<!-- Balance - outwards/inwards <c-y>d or <c-y>D -->
<div id="page">
    <section class="content">
        <h1>Doc example</h1>
            <p>Sit ex incidunt.</p>
    </section>
</div>

<!-- 1) Wrap abbreviation - works but no indents - <c-y>, -->
<div id="page">
    <p>'Hello world'</p>
</div>

<!-- 2) Manually indented -->
<div id="page">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>title</h1>
            <div class="content">
            <p>'Hello world'</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Go to next/previous Edit Point - <c-y>n Or <c-y>N -->
<ul>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
<div>

</div>

<script>
    var str = '<ul><li><a></a></li></ul>';
</script>

<!-- Split/Join Tag - <c-y>j -->
<div class="foo">
    cursor is here
</div>

<!-- Remove Tag - <c-y>k -->
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>Lorem animi impedit quibusdam.</p>
        <p>Sit neque obcaecati saepe</p>
        <p>Dolor hic voluptatum cumque</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tested `<c-y>d` and it works well. Did you put your cursor inside tag?

Comment: Dont know if a screenshot can be posted? But cursor was placed in p tag, in the space between "ex incidunt". In insert mode, ctrl + y + d pressed. The tag moved 1 tab space left. Thats all. I understand this should work out the box without any config changes in vimrc or anywhere else?